# Netlify: can I have a 301 redirect with custom HTTP headers?

Tags: http, redirect, http-status-code-301, cache-control, netlify

Using Netlify, can I add custom HTTP headers to a path on one domain but not another?

e.g. if I wanted my-domain.com to return a 301 with headers different to the headers returned by www.my-domain.com.

@talves has explained below why my initial approach (quoted) won’t work.

> Given the below in `netlify.toml`, I expect to see my custom
>   `Cache-Control` header (and NOT see the `Link` header) when I run
>   `curl -I http://hello-yoga.co.uk` but that's not happening.
>
> What am I doing wrong?
>
> ```
> [[headers]]
>   for = "/"
>   [headers.values]
>   Link = "</yoga-people.svg>; rel=preload; as=image"
>
> [[redirects]]
>   from = "http://hello-yoga.co.uk/*"
>   to = "https://www.hello-yoga.co.uk/:splat"
>   status = 301
>   force = true
>   headers = {Cache-Control = "public, max-age=2592000"}
> ```
>
> Result:
>
> ```
> $ curl -I http://hello-yoga.co.uk
> HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
> Cache-Control: public, max-age=0, must-revalidate
> Link: </yoga-people.svg>; rel=preload; as=image
> Location: https://www.hello-yoga.co.uk/
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Netlify support confirmed the only way to do this is with two Netlify apps:

1. For the www subdomain
2. For the apex/root domain

Answer (score 1):

The `headers` in the redirect are added request headers sent to the redirect proxy ([CUSTOM HEADERS IN PROXY REDIRECTS](https://www.netlify.com/docs/redirects/#structured-configuration))

These allow you to pass custom headers added to the redirect request that for example could help identify your request. These are not response headers that get passed through. Use `[[headers]]` for that purpose as you show for the Link.

Comment: Thanks @talves - I now understand that [[redirects]] headers are sent on to a server being proxied, not back to the client.